# JSON file resets after I reopen my application

Tags: swift

I am storing in a json file some user credentials (email, password, nickname). When I open the app on simulator and create multiple test accounts all works perfectly.

```swift
import Foundation

var users: [UserCredentials] = []

func save (email: String, password: String, nickname: String) {
    let newUsers = UserCredentials(email: email, password: password, nickname: nickname)
    users.append(newUsers)
    
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(users)
        let url = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("users.json")
        print(url.path)
        try data.write(to: url)
    } catch {
        print("Error encoding JSON: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The issue comes up when I reset the app and I type a new testuser. The json file resets instead of loading the testusers I saved before. Is there a way where the users stay saved in a file even when I restart the simulator?

Before reset:

````
    ```JSON
    [
  {
    "email" : "beforereset@yahoo.com",
    "nickname" : "beforereset12",
    "password" : "test1234A"
  },
  {
    "email" : "beforereset1@yahoo.com",
    "nickname" : "beforereset123",
    "password" : "test1234A"
  }
]

    ```
````

After reset:

````
```JSON
[
  {
    "email" : "afterreset@yahoo.com",
    "nickname" : "afterreset12",
    "password" : "1234testA"
  }
]
```
````

Where are the beforereset emails?

Comment: What do you meant by *The problems comes up when I reset the app*? You meant you delete app and re-install again?

Comment: when I simply rerun the app on xcode

Comment: No pictures of text please.

Comment: Please read the answer below first before continuing with your approach. But answering your question directly: when you launch the app, do you then fill your array first by reading out the contents? Or do you just start off with an empty array, save that when a new entry comes in and thus overwrite your old file?

Comment: I am starting with an empty array. Now I understand what I'm doing wrong. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I already told you in my answer. Read from the file into users before writing users to the file.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
try data.write(to: url)
```

...deletes the existing file's contents and replaces them. Thus every time `save` runs, the previous contents of the file are lost. (Unless of course you read those contents from the file into `users` before saving. But no code that you have shown us does that, so I have to conclude that you're not doing it at all.)

> Where are the beforereset emails?

Gone. You erased them.